# how to get ssh user traffic usage after session closed

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunnel

I have `openssh` service on server side for tunneling and everything is OK. but i need to know how much a user downloaded from the server after every ssh session is closed. some guys suggested `NetHogs` to log the network usage of all processes periodically, some suggested `iptables` owner module.
I don't know if any better ways exist or not or any alternative server side server to used instead of  `openssh` that support this option or is there any command to get all processes with their network usage (SEND AND RECEIVE bytes) ?